# Progress_bar for song

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i need a progress_bar that follow the time of a song. how can i set the end time of progress_bar exactly in the moment when the song finish?

ex. if my song has duration of 4:38 minutes how can i create a progress_bar for this specif period of time ( from when i click to 4:38 min after) ?

```
 var progressBar = $('#progress-bar'),
 width = 0;

 progressBar.width(width);

 var interval = setInterval(function() {
    width += 10;
    progressBar.css('width', width + '%');

    if (width >= 100) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000)
```

thanks.

Comment: How are you loading and playing the song?

Comment: I haven't a real song! I just want simulate the player, but for real playlist I had used this framework:http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/html5-music-player-updated/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4:38 is 4 * 60 + 38 = 278 seconds, which means every second the bar should move (1/278)*100 percent

```
var step = 100/(minutes*60 + seconds);

var interval = setInterval(function() {
   width += step;
   progressBar.css('width', width + '%');

  if (width >= 100) {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: GREAT! This is what i need..but It doesn't works! I do not know why, maybe wrong with the css. I have a lot of problems to start the progressbar.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I usually do:

```
var player = new Audio('http://goo.gl/mGVqyF');

player.play();
var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
     document.getElementById('timebar').style.width = player.currentTime
                                                    / player.duration
                                                    * winWidth +'px';
},100);

// stop the setInterval when song ended
player.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
});
```

It does not guess when it is going to end, it grabs this info from the player with `currentTime` and `duration`.

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use related HTML5 media events like `timeupdate` and `ended`.
You may see them in action at http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Regarding your code it would be like

```
var progressBar = $('#progress-bar'), width = 0;

progressBar.width(width);

$(audio).on('timeupdate',function(e){
  var progress = this.currentTime / this.duration;
  progressBar.css('width', progress*100+'%');
});
```

You probably don't use HTML5 media. So, anyway I don't recommend to use `setInterval` in that case. Use a ways similar to way I showed above.

Comment: i think you might need parens:  (progress*100)+'%'

Comment: The `onTimeUpdate` idea is good, but unfortunately, it happens at such a frequency that you will get lag, especially when using jQuery. Setting a timeout or an interval will help keep things under control.

Comment: Wasting 2(!) bytes of code. Multiplication has a higher priority :)

Comment: @blex, as I know, `timeupdate` fires every 250ms. I don't think it's frequency

Comment: Really? Oh, then I don't know why, but when I use this event I usually get lag, but not with an interval.

Comment: @Novelist: Normally, I'd grumble over someone trying to save two bytes of code --- but in Javascript, it's important....