# count minutes and seconds onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi need to catch up specif minutes and seconds, and i need to see feed.
HTML SPAN:

```
<span class="minutes">0</span>:
<span class="seconds">00</span>
```

JQuery:

```
function count_timesong(end_time){
    var time_parts = end_time.split(':');
    var minutes = time_parts[0];
    var seconds = time_parts[1];
    $('.minutes').countTo({from: 0, to: minutes,speed: 600000});
    $('.seconds').countTo({from: 00, to: seconds,speed: 10000});
}
```

i need to increment minutes every 60seconds and stop when arrive to end_time ( ex. 4:38 )

Comment: In other words, you need a counter, don't you?

Comment: yes, the first answer it's really what i need !! now i need to merge it with a progress bar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like,

```
var totalSeconds = 0;
var clr = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
var endMinute=1;
var endSecond=5;
function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    var s=totalSeconds % 60,
        m=parseInt(totalSeconds / 60);
    if(s==endSecond && m==endMinute) {
        clearInterval(clr);
    }
    $('#seconds').text(s);
    $('#minutes').text(m);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/d26vt7s3/)**

Updated Demo with [progress bar](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/d26vt7s3/3/)

Comment: THANKS!!! IT'S PERFECT! Can I create the progress bar that increment like seconds (totalSeconds)? like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650900/progress-bar-for-song but i don't know how merge these.

Comment: can I close the progressbar in a DIV Whit specific width ?

Comment: You mean to say you want to stop progress bar, without waiting it to be 100%. If yes then you need to use another setInterval for prgress bar and clear it on an event like button click.